# Stack init package not found

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

When trying to build an existing project with Stack I got errors like

```
bv not found
- Genesis requires >=0.3 && <0.4 && -any
- exp requires -any
```

during `stack init`. The packages are all installed in a sandbox and are from hackage. I'm almost sure Stack doesn't look into the sandbox, but why can't it find the packages from hackage? I'm also able to build just by running `cabal build`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stack does not look at Hackage at first. It tries to build your project using only packages from a snapshot of [Stackage](http://www.stackage.org/) (you can find the exact snapshot you are using in the `resolver` field of `stack.yaml`). `bv` does not seem to be in Stackage (at least it is not in the [latest LTS snapshot](http://www.stackage.org/lts-3.0)). Fortunately, the issue is easy to solve: just run `stack solver --modify-stack-yaml`. That will identify all non-Stackage dependencies and add them to the `extra-deps` field of `stack.yaml`. From that point on, those dependencies will be built somewhere in the `.stack-work` subdirectory of your project, in a very similar way to packages in a cabal-install sandbox.

Comment: `stack solver --modify-stack-yaml` says `Couldn't find .cabal file in: .` but I do have a `Genesis.cabal`

Comment: @rem After cloning [your repository](https://github.com/remysucre/Genesis) I did not get this specific error (though there were a few version bounds issues). What does `stack version` say? (I am using the newly-released 0.1.3.1).

Comment: Version 0.1.3.1, Git revision 908b042...46ed2b804d7. Do I need to do anything before `stack solver --modify-stack-yaml`?

Comment: I didn't notice this before, but in the error there's actually `Running /usr/local/bin/cabal --config-file=/tmp/cabal-solver8108/cabal.config install -v --dry-run --only-dependencies --reorder-goals --max-backjumps=-1 --package-db=clear --package-db=global exited with ExitFailure 1`. But I succeeded in running the same command outside stack

Comment: @rem I suggest you (1) in all .cabal files of your project, raise the upper bound of `haskell-src-exts` to `< 1.17`, and that of `random` to `< 1.2`, to match the versions in reasonably recent LTS snapshots; (2) delete `stack.yaml` and run `stack init --resolver lts-2.22` (the latest LTS for GHC 7.8.4, which I assume is the one in your system and what you want to use); and (3) run `stack solver --modify-stack-yaml`.

Comment: @rem To sum it up, the main issue is that the version bounds for `haskell-src-exts` need bumping in some places (the earliest Stackage snapshot already used 1.15) and are inconsistent in others (one of the files asked for 1.16.*). If you don't need stack to handle all those .cabal files in the hidden directories of your project, you can make your life easier by passing the `--ignore-subdirs` option to `stack init`.

Comment: Succeed! Thanks so much