# Haskell package Not on Stackage, then how?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, stackage

I want to use [HList: Heterogeneous lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList), but the package seems not on Stackage.

I currently use stack. In this case what is the option besides going back to use Cabal?

Comment: Possibly duplicate, or at least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016256/stack-init-package-not-found/32016828#32016828

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`extra-deps`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#extra-deps) in `stack.yaml`:

```yaml
extra-deps:
- HList-0.5.2.0
```

Stack should prompt you to if you add the package as a dependency in the Cabal file.

Comment: Thanks! it works. By the way, the package name and URL was wrong, and modified to `HList: Heterogeneous lists`.

Comment: Please see the right syntax though, you have to pick an exact version.

Comment: Thanks, it actually did not work from the start. I misunderstood. and now I get this 

`haskell-test/package.yaml: Ignoring unrecognized field $.extra-deps` for unknown reason, on `stack build`. any idea?

Comment: Put this in `stack.yaml`, not `package.yaml`.

Comment: Eah, right, you wrote that too. Thanks again.